# Find information on calculation view?

Tags: hana

I 'm trying to create a procedure which can check information on calculation view.
For this purpose I would need to know if  calculation view:

is cross client ?

if there is a keyfigures ?

I also need to get commentary and cardinality on every node and to know if the node is rename.

Is there a way to get those information ?

I found interesting table on `SYS.VIEW` but most of them are empty.

If you have any idea please share it with me,

thanks in advance,

Etienne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you are looking for is encoded in the actual XML source code for the calculation views. You will have to parse this XML to evaluate this.
Be aware that this format is not externally supported and can change without prior notice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Lars. Do you know if it's possible to read XML source code with sql script in a procedure ?